# programmatically generated tex file - overfull \vbox

Tags: sectioning, lists

I am generating a long list of files, sections and subsections based on a folder structure.

The ouput is currently this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{datetime}
\setmainfont[]{Source Sans Pro}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\title{List of uploaded talks}
\date{Last updated: \today~\currenttime}
\author{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{List of uploaded talks}
\rhead{Last updated: \dayofweekname{\day}{\month}{\year}~\currenttime}

\begin{document}
\section*{03 - Tuesday}

\subsection*{10.30 Session 1}

\subsubsection*{10.30 - Plenary, David Reby}

\subsubsection*{11.20 - Oral presentations}

\begin{itemize}

\item OP\_DogDirectedSpeech\_Lesch\_CSF2018\_powerpoint.pptx
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection*{11.50 - PK presentations}

\begin{itemize}

\item PK - AndreaSommese.pptx
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{13.00 Session 2}

\subsubsection*{13.00 - Oral presentations}

\begin{itemize}

\item OP - Rowena Packer.pptx
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection*{13.30 - PK presentations}

\begin{itemize}

\item Carla.Eatherington\_PK.pptx
\item Zamansky-PK.pptx
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{15.00 Session 3}

\subsubsection*{15.00 - Plenary, Anna V. Kukekova}

\subsubsection*{15.50  - Oral presentations}

\subsubsection*{16.20 - PK presentations}

\subsection*{17.10 Session 4}

\subsubsection*{17.10 - Oral presentations}

\subsubsection*{17.40 - PK presentations}

\section*{04 - Wednesday}

\subsection*{11:00 - Session 6}

\subsubsection*{11:00 - Plenary, Miha Krofel}

\subsubsection*{11:50 - Poster teasers, video abstracts}

\subsection*{14:45 - Session 7}

\subsubsection*{14:45 - Plenary, Juliane Kaminski}

\subsubsection*{16:05 - Round table}

\subsection*{9:00 - Session 5}

\subsubsection*{10:20 - PK presentations}

\subsubsection*{9:00 - Plenary, Nicola J. Rooney}

\subsubsection*{9:50 - Oral presentations}

\section*{05 - Thursday}

\subsection*{11:00 - Session 9}

\subsubsection*{11:00 - Young scientist talk, Charlotte Duranton}

\subsubsection*{11:50 - Poster teasers, videoabstracts}

\subsection*{14:30 - Session 10}

\subsubsection*{14:30 - Plenary, Bridgett vonHoldt}

\subsubsection*{15:20 - Oral presentations}

\subsubsection*{15:50 - PK presentations}

\subsection*{16:30 - Session 11}

\subsubsection*{16:30 - Oral presentations}

\subsubsection*{16:45 - PK presentations}

\subsection*{9:00 - Session 8}

\subsubsection*{10:20 - PK presentations}

\subsubsection*{9:00 - Plenary, Greger Larson}

\subsubsection*{9:50 - Oral presentations}

\section*{06 - Friday}

\subsection*{11:00 - Session 13}

\subsubsection*{11:00 - Oral presentations}

\subsubsection*{11:30 - PK presentations}

\subsection*{9:00 - Session 12}

\subsubsection*{10:20 - PK presentations}

\subsubsection*{9:00 - Plenary, Claudia Fugazza}

\subsubsection*{9:50 - Oral presentations}

\section*{Uncategorized}
\begin{itemize}

\item 0R-csf2018-daniela-poertl-epigenetics.pptx
\item CSF2018\_detailed\_program.pdf
\item Carla\_Eatherington.PT.pptx
\item Csibra\_Barbara\_CSF\_ADHD\_personality\_inhibition\_OP.pptx
\item Gogoleva\_Fox\_vocalizations\_oral.zip
\item Hielscher\_physical activity\_PT.pptx
\item J.E.vanderLaan\_SleepyShelterDogs\_OP.zip
\item Johnston\_PK\_420.pptx
\item NotFoundError
\item NotFoundError (2)
\item Oral presentation CSF 2018 short.docx
\item PK S.Corsetti.ppsx
\item PK\_CSF2018-Christoph\_Jung\_scavenging\_hypotheses.pptx
\item PK\_Fanni Lehoczki\_puppy separation calls.pptx
\item PK\_Pongracz\_CSF2018\_Sizeawareness.pptx
\item PT-vaataja-dogactivitytracker.mp4
\item Paula Calvo Effects of dog assisted therapy PK.pptx
\item PechaKucha\_CSF2018-Christoph\_Jung.pptx
\item Range\_Recruitment for cooperation.pptx
\item csf2018-daniela-poertl (2).pptx
\item csf2018-daniela-poertl.pptx
\item malandrucco\_Video abstract.mp4
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This seems ok to me, but the [output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l0g8yslvFvOfIaauePV9SY55DgSO4K0m/view?usp=sharing) is clearly wrong. What is going wrong here? I am getting this error: `Overfull \vbox (329.73178pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []` but I do not see why this should occur at all.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: No page break is possible between section titles. Are you sure you want to abuse `\section` and `\subsection` for that?

Comment: Well, that does answer the question. I added some `\newpages` so each days sections fit on a page so it now seems ok. But yeah, in a general case (where you could have more subsection for example) using sectioning for this would not be a good idea. I guess you'd have to go for lists or something?

Comment: @fbence Nested lists are definitely the way to go.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem but `datetime` is obsolete and has been replaced by [`datetime2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2).